# Patient transportation

Tags: optaplanner, jsprit

I am searching for algorithm and jsprit or optaplanner project seems to be in order to resolve my problem. We only work with Java.
I have take a look at jsprit bicycle example, an entry point, and now I need to solve a problem arround patient transportation.

- A stretcher can carry a bed, a wheelchair or a valid patient. He can carry a wheelchair and a valid at the same time if they go to the same area and come from a same area.
- for long distance, a bed require 2 stretchers
- a bed mover (a kind of electric truck fixed to the bed) replace 1
  stretcher
- bed movers are most efficient for long distance but may be use for
  short too
- a bed mover only helps for bed (nor for wheelchair nor valid patient)
- when finish, the bed mover stays in place or returns empty to a park
  area (maybe 1..n places)

General rules :

- the total time of transportation per agent must be as equals as
  possible as each others (equity)
- transports are time windowed and delay must be as short as possible
  (depending on priorities)
- new transport requests comes every time
- it's better to use bed movers than 2 stretchers

Can you give me how to start to resolve this kind of problem. Do you think it's possible?

Regards

Comment: If you go with OptaPlanner, take a look at the VRP with time windows example and adjust it to your needs (= your constraints).

Comment: Thank you for your comment Geoffrey. I have seen this example in OptaPlanner. The main constraint is about two transporters at the same time for the same job. I can't figure out how to implement this. Anything else is a problem of cost...

Comment: Quick hack would be to put 2 Customer instances on that 1 location, add a hard constraint that those 2 customers need to be serviced by a different vehicle and then adjust the ArrivalTimeListener to delay the first arriving vehicle until the second vehicle arrives.